# Regex for form.controls['property']

Tags: regex, angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find replace thousands of strings in code - `form.controls['property']` with `form.get('property')` where `property` is a variable. 
So far I got find expression `.controls\['\w+'\]` with replace expression `.get\('\w+'\)` but VSCode is replacing `.controls['products']` with `.get\('\w+'\)` for string `productForm.controls['products'].controls.length`. I need to replace it with `productForm.get('products').controls.length` Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses `()` capture a group. Money sign `$` accesses a group by index.

```
.controls\['(\w+)'\]

.get('$1')
```

This is the result in VS Code:

[image: the regex successfully finds and replaces the target text.]

See also: [What flavor of Regex does Visual Studio Code use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use/42184299)