# Visual Studio Code: Search on multiple terms

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

We are trying to figure out a way to search for all the files that contain multiple terms.  For instance that reference the Orders file and then the status field.  Searching for the status field alone does not work as orders have status, items have status, ...

There are two options that would fulfill the need we have for searching that I can come up with:

1. Perform a search and then be able to search only within the results of the first search.
2. Perform a search using the AND keyword (Orders AND status) or equivalent regular expression concept using (?=) syntax.

Visual studio code does not appear to support either of these methods.  Any suggestions how to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use

Comment: Maybe duplicated (or at least related) to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944569/search-in-vs-code-for-multiple-terms