# Search in VS Code for multiple terms

Tags: regex, search, visual-studio-code

Suppose I search on VS Code the terms 'word1 word2'. Then it finds all the occurrences where 'word1' is followed by 'word2'. In reality I want to find all the files where word1 and word2 occur, but they don't have to be consecutive. How can I do it?

Answer (score 102):

Use regex flag and search for `(word1[\s\S\n]*word2)|(word2[\s\S\n]*word1)`

---

Made a small extension based on @tonix regex:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.search

Comment: You will need some word boundaries in there too '\b' unless having word1 or word2 within another word like 'backword1' for example is not a problem for you.  And I have to use \\n to get it to work in the search across files panel.

Comment: @Alex Could you please explain `[\s\S\n]*`?

Comment: I don't remember, should match "anything".

Comment: Genius! (I will not learn regex any time soon despite its usefulness.)

Comment: Can we constrain this so that all words must be on the same line? Update, this seems to work: `(word1[\s\S]*word2)|(word2[\s\S]*word1)`

Comment: @Jonny try `(\bfirst\b.*\bsecond\b)|(\bsecond\b.*\bfirst\b)` unless you don't care about lines like `firstblah blahsecond` matching. See https://regex101.com/r/xv9H1q/1

Comment: @Nikhil here you are: 
`\s` - match any whitespace character
`\S` - match any non-whitespace character
`\n` - match a linefeed character
`[\s\S\n]` - match exactly one of the above three
`[\s\S\n]*` - match zero or more of any of the above three - that is, in effect, "anything at any length".

In theory `\s` should also match `\n`, but this does not work in the VS Code search field.

Comment: @GergelyMáté `\S` works in which regex standard. Could you please provide reference?

Comment: @Nikhil it works both with [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) and [Rust](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.6/regex/#perl-character-classes-unicode-friendly) regexes. I think it comes from Perl.

Comment: This can get really out of hand when you have more than two terms.

Answer (score 59):

Here is also a simple way for simple needs - use this as regex

```
(word1)|(word2)|(word3)
```

It may not cover some cases, but has been working fine for me, and easy to remember to type it in.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It's the simplest working solution presented so far, and handles only what the question was asking for.

Comment: This matches OR. It was asked for AND. I used [Alex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944629/1097958) instead.

Comment: Good point, these are different use cases.  This regex I use when I want to highlight all the keywords in a file

Answer (score 15):

To apply logical and
(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)

To apply logical or
(word1)|(word2)|(word3)

Comment: This only finds them if they are on the same line.  Not in the same file as requested.

Comment: simple and easy to understand. thank you

Answer (score 9):

VSCode has an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16488) to support multiple searches. You may want to get on there and push them a little.

Comment: This is now supported, you can search for the term then open in editor and use ctrl + f to search the search results thanks @pushkin

Comment: just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66766568/9921564) for this so it's easier in the future but you could probably edit this answer

Comment: This is not what the OP requested.

Answer (score 5):

For you guys,

if you want to search for multiple words (more than 2) at once in a single file and all the words must appear in the file at least once (logical AND), you can use the following regex which leverages lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=[\s\S\n]*(word1))(?=[\s\S\n]*(word2))(?=[\s\S\n]*(word3))(?=[\s\S\n]*(word4))[\s\S\n]*$
```

A global search with this pattern will only return all the files that contain `word1` AND `word2` AND `word3` AND `word4` in any order (e.g. `word4` may appear at the beginning and/or `word2` may appear at the end of the file).

I also wrote a little Python CLI helper which creates the regex automatically for you given the patterns you want to AND (though creating the regex by hand is pretty straightforward).

Copy the following code, paste it in a new file and save it somewhere on your machine (I've called it `regex_and_lookahead.py`). Then make the file executable with `chmod +x ./regex_and_lookahead.py` (important, I used Python 3.6, the literal prefix `f` -> `f'(?=[\s\S\\n]*({arg}))'` won't work in previous versions):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv

args = argv[1:]
regex = '^'
for arg in args:
    regex += f'(?=[\s\S\\n]*({arg}))'
regex += '[\s\S\\n]*$'

print(regex)
```

Usage:

```
./regex_and_lookahead.py word1 word2 word3 word4
```

Will generate the above regex. You can also use it to generate more complex regexes cause each parameter can have regex characters in it!

As an example:

```
./regex_and_lookahead.py "pattern with space" "option1|option2" "\bword3\b" "(repeated pattern\.){6}"
```

Will generate the following regex:

```
^(?=[\s\S\n]*(pattern with space))(?=[\s\S\n]*(option1|option2))(?=[\s\S\n]*(\bword3\b))(?=[\s\S\n]*((repeated pattern\.){6}))[\s\S\n]*$
```

Which will match a file if and only if **all** of the following conditions are true:

- There's at least one occurrence of the string `pattern with space`;
- There's at least one occurrence of either `option1` or `option2`;
- There's at least one occurrence of the word `word3` delimited by word boundary assertions;
- There is at least one occurrence of the string `repeated pattern.` repeated 6 times (i.e.: `repeated pattern.repeated pattern.repeated pattern.repeated pattern.repeated pattern.repeated pattern.`).

As you can see, the sky is the only limit. Have fun!

Comment: your regex doesn't seem to work in the VS Code sidebar Search. Does it work on your end? The VS Code sidebar Search uses the Rust Regex engine. Is your regex written in that flavor?

Comment: It used to work in 2019. Honestly I didn't try to use this regex after a while and I don't know if it works now as VS Code had several updates. What error do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but the search doesn't match with any files, even though there are files in my workspace containing the search terms. I'm using VS Code 1.54.3.

Answer (score 4):

This extension: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), I am the author, makes it quite easy to do any number of sequential searches across files only using the files from previous search results for future searches.

There is a variable `${resultsFiles}` that resolves to those previous search results files and can be used in the `"filesToInclude"` argument.  Here is a sample keybinding

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {
    
    "find": ["first", "second"],
    "delay": 2000,              // necessary to allow results to populate
    // delay may need to be longer if you are searching a lot of files 

    "replace": ["", "knuckles"],   // optional
    
    "filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],
    "filesToExclude": "Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\keybindings.json",
    
    "isRegex": true,

    // so that the first search will be triggered and produce results
    "triggerSearch": true,

    "triggerReplaceAll": [false, true]   // optional
  }
}
```

1. `"find": ["first", "second"],` : search for `first` and then search for `second`
2. `"filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],` : clear the `filesToInclude` on the first search, on second search use the `resultFiles` from the first search
3. You can do as many sequential searches as you like
4. The `finds` can be regex's and as complex as you wish

[image: perform sequential searches using the files only from previous searches]

Answer (score 3):

The original question asked to do a single search for files containing two separate words in the same file. Below is what I do to search for two (or more) words in the same file by using multiple searches.:

1. Search Like you normally do
2. Click on "Open in editor"
   [image]
3. Adjust the context line count. (The higher the context count the more you can search for that second term, but the more non relevant searches you bring in)
   [image: ,]
4. Hit Cmd + F (or equivalent if not on mac) and search there. In the image below I have narrowed it down to 53 hits. I can manually skip through until I find it.
   [image]

Need even more Fine tuning?

1. Same Steps as 1 - 3
2. Copy the contents to a file. (In the image below I saved it to a file called haystack.ts)
3. Search there for a third word. (In the image below I have now narrowed it down to 7 searches.)
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported, you can search for the term then open in editor and use ctrl + f to search the search results thanks [@pushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3479456/pushkin)

Comment: I think that in this case, the second search is done file-by-file right? If so, this is not very efficient when more than a handful files are returned.

Comment: Not really, it opens one new file with all the occurrences and you search in that file

Comment: Thanks ! But doesn't the `open in editor` option presents only a few lines around each occurrence and not the whole files? Such that the ctrl+f is limited to those few lines within each file? I might have gotten something wrong on my end.

Comment: yes that is correct, not a perfect solution...

Comment: My initial search gets a hit of over 2000 files. I do not want to then open all of those (I don't think it even could) for the second search.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Open new Search Editor command`, through command pallete,  You can map it to any keybinding you'd like in the Keybindings Editor. I mapped to `cmd+shift+i`
[image]

This is helpful for me!
There is one more way, using `up/ down` arrow key in search editor, moves us across our search history, **even this is useful**,

> It needs a little bent of mind to accept that it is equivalent to having multiple search editors (what IntelliJ etc provides) but without persistence!

Comment: This does not address the question. The question regards a single search for files containing two separate words in the same file, not separate search results for two different words across all files.

Comment: the answer will still be useful addition to this question, therefore not removing it.