# How to search by two keywords in IDE (WebStorm and/or VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I work on a project with a huge codebase. I need to find files where both "token" and "subscription" are mentioned. If I search separately (token or subscription) I get hundreds of files with mentions of these words.

Is there any way to search for files where both keywords are mentioned?

I work with WebStorm and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You can use regex. Try `(token)|(subscription)`. In VS Code on Windows, CTRL+F to open the Find window, ALT+R to enable regex, and then type in that expression.

Comment: Above comment is for logical OR. You asked for logical AND. For that, try: `(token[\s\S\n]*subscription)|(subscription[\s\S\n]*token)`. I borrowed this logic from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49944569/5056494)

Comment: write a simple shell script that uses `grep -l`