# Search for all files *not* containing a string in VS Code

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, using the search capability, how can I search for all files that *do not* contain a certain string? In this case - "OnPush"

Comment: Probably `^(?![\S\s\r]*OnPush)`, but I can't test now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I enable Regex and try that, as well as other possible regex solutions, VS code responds with "Expression Matches Everything"

Comment: May want to check info on the regex flavor first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a VS Code extension called [Reverse Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanishSarwar.reverse-search)
It can find files that do not contain a specific string

Comment: Is it possible to search only in specific folder and in specific files like .php?

Comment: @IvanTopić yes, you can include or exclude files using this extension.

Comment: Reverse Search didn't work for me. I enter "$layout" to find files that don't contain it and in next step I enter "controllers/**" since I only want to find files in controllers folder which don't have $layout in them, but Reverse Search still shows me files containing $layout!

Comment: As of early 2023, Reverse Search v2.0.2 worked very well for me.

Answer (score 40):

In general regex, to search for anything that does not contain a certain string, you do `stringbefore(?!string)` That is a negative lookahead, it says that only match if whatever you specify as `string` is not  present. In your case it would be something like `[\W\w]+(?!OnPush)`

But, Negative Lookaheads aren't supported in VS Code Search... So you can't do much.

Comment: Try now. I'm downloading VS code right now will test there

Comment: Negative look-ahead isn't supported in VS Code search: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30735

Comment: You need to enable "search.usePCRE2" in VS Code to use negative look-ahead.

Comment: You don't need to ensable the `PCRE2` setting anymore - in fact it is deprecated.  Vscode will use PCRE2 as a fallback automatically now.

Comment: VSCode (v 1.50.1) Search works. e.g search for a comma not followed by whitespace `,(?!\s)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in VSCode (v 1.73), I tried to find files in a folder that do not contain the string "$layout" using regex [\W\w]+(?!\$layout), but it still finds files containing "$layout". Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^(?!.*abc.*).*
```

This matches all lines not containig "abc" & works in VSCode (tested with 1.85.1)

Comment: The question asks to find a _file_ that does not contain the string. This finds every other line in the file, except the line with that string.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using a regular expression in your search query. Use the following pattern:

```
ChangeDetectionStrategy(?!.*OnPush)
```

This regular expression utilizes a negative lookahead (?!.*OnPush), ensuring that the match does not contain the string "OnPush" following the **ChangeDetectionStrategy**.

In Visual Studio Code, make sure you have the "Use Regular Expression" option enabled. You can find this option on the left side of the search input box or use the shortcut `Alt + R` to toggle it on.

This way, you can find occurrences of ChangeDetectionStrategy but exclude those set to OnPush.