# How to use regular expressions in VS Code

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a question about regular expressions. I'm using VS Code and trying to search and replace € (price).

I have a JSON file and in that file a have price like this:
"price": 120.000 € a trying to remove € so everything should look like this:
"price": 120.000
Please help, thank you all.

Comment: You mean directly in the editor or using code? If by code, what language are you using?

Comment: We are here to help but have you tried anything?

Comment: I repeat comment from Cid. Which language do you use ? C++, VB.Net C#, F#, Python, Node.js ? You say that you have tried. Ok, but can you give the code you have tried ? That can help us to help you :-)

Comment: Hello, i just want to replace in json file, directly in the editor. I try to use search and replace but I also have a content and inside content is also some prices with €. When I use search and replace, it replace all € in file but I only wants replace in "price":"120.000 €" to "price":"120.000" . I tried somethng like this:^[^/\n](?:/[^/\n]+)*€

Comment: Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42184299/8398549), this is JavaScript based.

Comment: @jomskris can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54197246/edit) your question and add your RegEx attempts instead of directly in comment?

Comment: `"price": 120.000 €` is not JSON. Are you sure about the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`("price"\s?:\s?"(?:\d+\.?)+)(\s?€)"` to be replaced by `$1"`

`$1` is the first captured group. In that RegEx, this is : `("price"\s?:\s?"(?:\d+\.?)+)`

- 1st Capturing Group `("price"\s?:\s?"(?:\d+\.?)+)` :

-> `"price"` matches the characters `"price"` literally (case sensitive)

-> `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

--> `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

-> `:` matches the character `:` literally (case sensitive)

-> `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

--> `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

-> `"` matches the character `"` literally (case sensitive)

- Non-capturing group `(?:\d+\.?)+`

-> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

--> `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

--> `\.?` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

- 2nd Capturing Group `(\s?€)`

-> `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

--> `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

-> `€` matches the character `€` literally (case sensitive)

-> `"` matches the character `"` literally (case sensitive)

This will be replaced by `$1"` which is the first captured group followed by `"`

[Test it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/aK24fk/2)