# avoid in between character in regex pattern

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am trying to find the component in all files with specific attribute. Tried this regex pattern `<Button[^>]*[\n\s]+className[^>]*>`. 95% it works fine.

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/SGB0aN/3/)

You can see in this above example. Button component with condition attribute won't match. It has className attribute too. It should match. It didn't match because of this greater than character **`=>`** in condition attribute line. So, It stops even before the component close tag.

How do I avoid in between greater than character (**`>`**) in this regex pattern?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: or in fact anything other than the most simple of cases (IMO)   regex produces hard to read and hard to debug code and it seems it may not even be possible to parse html with regex.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to get as a result? All entries between button tags (including all atributes)?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes. Get all results of button tags with className attributes. not all attributes

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Ok. But, if I need to use condition in attributes I have to use it in open & close curly brackets `{}`. So, if close tag used `>` in between curly brackets, it should be avoided. Any way like this?

Comment: `<Button(?:\w+={[^{}]*}|[^>])*\sclassName=(?:\w+={[^{}]*}|[^>])*>`. See https://regex101.com/r/SGB0aN/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you post your comment as an answer with explanation. It will be useful for me and other users.. :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works fine in above link. But, it doesn't work as expected in VS code editor. Error messages show _incomplete quantifier_

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tried this `<Button(?:\w+=\{[^\{\}]*\}|[^>])*\sclassName=(?:\w+=\{[^\{\}]*\}|[^>])*>` after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422987/incomplete-quantifier-on-regex-in-vscode). It matches in VS code editor.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Please don't use that link for explaining why you shouldn't use regexes for HTML parsing. OP will not understand it.  Here's a more illustrative page I put together: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match any char but `>` or an attribute (a chunk of word chars) followed with `=` and then a substring between curly braces one or more times with `(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*\}|[^>])*`.

Also, you should keep in mind Visual Studio Code regex engine requires `{` and `}` outside of a character class to be escaped.

The pattern will look like

```
<Button(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*\}|[^>])*\sclassName=(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*\}|[^>])*>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/30khii/1).

**Details**

- `<Button` - a literal string
- `(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*\}|[^>])*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\w+=\{[^{}]*\}` - one or more letters, digits or underscores, `={`, zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^>]`  - any char other than `>`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `className=`  - a literal text
- `(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*\}|[^>])*` - see above
- `>` - a  `>` char.

Comment: Sorry to ask you through comment. This one doesn't match `<Button onChange={(value) => {this.state;}} className={style.textArea}></Button>`

Comment: @KaruppiahRK Yes, because of nested curly braces. Whether it is possible for you to solve or not, you should name the regex library you are using.

Comment: regex library name means? Sorry I don't get it. I tried to solve it. But couldn't. I don't have enough knowledge in regex pattern.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK What is the programming language?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: React

Comment: @KaruppiahRK So, JavaScript, sorry, no recursion allowed.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: Yes. JavaScript

Comment: Just tried this `<Button\b(?:\w+=\{[^\{\}]*\}|[^<])*\sclassName=(?:\w+=\{[^\{\}]*\}|[^>])*>` [link] (https://regex101.com/r/SGB0aN/6). This one somehow matches the cases. But, I am not sure whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK If you only have one nested parentheses level you may use `<Button(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\}|[^>])*\sclassName=(?:\w+=\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\}|[^>])*>`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGB0aN/7).