# vs-code: Append a text to multiple opened files using regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to append some text to multiple files. Is this possible in VS-Code with 
Edit->"Replace in Files" using regex?

[image]

\z (only the end of text) is not working here - invalid regular expression.

Comment: I looked at https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.10/regex/#empty-matches because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use mentions that Rust regex is used in vs-code.

Comment: Try `$(?![\w\W])`

Comment: wow! it works - could you please explain this regex for me? or add a link with explanation?

Comment: VSC is run on Chrome V8 (Javascript) so unlikely it uses the Rust regex syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the end of line that has no character immediately to the right:

```
$(?![\w\W])
```

Here, `$` matches an end of line position and `(?![\w\W])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if any char appears immediately to the right of that location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcCI5B/2) where `m` flag is enabled and makes `$` match end of line positions, as in Visual Studio Code, and due to `(?![\w\W])` it only matches at the very end of the text.