# Find \n and replace with \r\n in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a legacy system that only accepts Windows `\r\n` and I want to edit a file in VS Code that has just `\n` to have `\r\n`.

I'm trying to use a Regex replace:

[image: regex replace in VS Code]

But this puts literal `\r` in instead of the whitespace char.

I've tried putting a newline in the replacement using `SHIFT+ENTER`:

[image: SHIFT+ENTER replace in VS Code]

But this just puts in `\n`.

How do I change the line feed chars used and save the file in VS Code?

Comment: I think you must turn off regex, because it detects new line in your case.

Comment: use command `Change End of Line Sequence`

Comment: Your approach doesn't work because line feeds in the search and replace dialogue seem to be an abstraction, so you don't need to craft different expressions for different EOL styles. In any case, this program seems to support up to three different regexp engines, depending on settings and context, and I suspect they've been slightly customised. ([What flavor of Regex does Visual Studio Code use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use?)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the text "LF" in the bottom bar on the right, click on it and select "CRLF". Or press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and enter `Change End of Line Sequence`.

No idea why your approach doesn't work. Nor does `\x0D` or `\15` get recognized. I'd call it a bug.

---

For multiple files, on Linux, I'd do it outside of the editor, e.g., with

```
find somedir -name '*.someext' -exec perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r\n/' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one
In the local searchbox (Ctrl + F) you can insert newlines by pressing Ctrl + Enter.
https://www.graef.io/find-and-replace-with-a-newline-in-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code provides an option to **Select End of Line Sequence** in its taskbar on bottom right:

[image: Select End of Line Sequence in VSC taskbar]

When clicked, it'll provide an option to choose between **CRLF** (Carriage return and Line feed: Windows default) and **LF** (Line feed alone: Linux supported):

[image: Select End of Line Sequence in VSC Selector]

Make sure to **save** the file once the EOL sequence is changed.

Answer (score -2):

Just press **Ctrl+H** and select regex replace. Then start input:

Find what: **^\n**

Replace with: **\r\n**

Comment: Did you read the question? There's a screenshot of me doing that. This is over a year old so maybe it's been fixed since then.

Comment: @Keith, Not, you're not right at all. On your screenshot you did a little bit other thing. In my case my option helped me against your method that on screenshot

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you added `^` before `\n` to avoid replacing it unless it's at the start/line-start (depending on `m` flag), but the regex `\n` _finds_ it just fine - your answer is a tweak to the find regex but the problem is the replace treated `\r\n` as a literal string.