# Regex to replace whitespace in Markdown URLs

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I've a bunch of Markdown links with whitespace, and I need to replace the whitespace with `%20`. So far I've hacked a few solutions, but none that work in VSCode, or do exactly what I'm looking for.

This is the URL format conversion I need:

```
[My link](../../_resources/my resource.jpg)
[My link](../../_resources/my%20resource.jpg)
```

`\s+(?=[^(\)]*\))` will work on any whitespace inside brackets - but gives false positives as it works on anything with brackets.

`(?:\]\(|(?!^)\G)[^]\s]*\K\h+` does the job, but I'm getting some "Invalid Escape Character" messages in VSCode, so I assume the language isn't compatible.

I've been trying to identify the link on the characters `](` but as I'm relatively new to regex, struggling a bit.

I tried with this regex: `(?<=\]\()s\+` as this `(?<=\]\().+` correctly identifies the url, but it doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: VSCode find in files doesn't support variable length lookbehind, even though find/replace in the open file does support this. Open to any other solutions before I dive into writing a script!

Comment: You can't do that with a single regex pass in VSCode, so use Notepad++ that has a Boost regex engine and also provides Find/Replace in Files option. The regex is `(\G(?!\A)|\[[^][]*]\()([^()\s]*)\s+(?=[^()]*\))` and replace with `$1$2%20`.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode regex does not support `\K`, `\G`, or `\h`, but it does support Lookbehinds with non-fixed width. So, you may use something like the following:

```
(?<=\]\([^\]\r\n]*)[^\S\r\n]+
```

**[Online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5D%5C%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%29%5B%5E%5CS%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B&i=%5BMy%20link%5D%28..%2F..%2F_resources%2Fmy%20resource.jpg%29%0D%0A%5BMy%20link%5D%28..%2F..%2F_resources%2Fmy%2520resource.jpg%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%5BMy%20link%5D%28..%2F..%2F_resources%2Fmy%20good%20resource.jpg%29&r=%2520)**.

Comment: I believe the pattern is self-explanotary. If there's something not clear, please let me know and I'll break it down for you.

Comment: Can you replace `[^\S\r\n]` with a space character (i.e., if you are not concerned about tabs, vertical tabs and formfeeds)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=\]\([^\]]*)\s+(?=[^()]*\))
```

Replace with `%20`. See the demo screenshot:

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?<=\]\([^\]]*)` -  a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `](` and then any zero or more chars other than `]`
- `\s+` - any one or more whitespace chars (other than line break chars in Visual Studio Code, if there is no `\n` or `\r` in the regex, `\s`does not match line break chars)
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.

**Since you are using it in Find/Replace in Files**, this lookbehind solution won't work.

You can use Notepad++ with

```
(\G(?!\A)|\[[^][]*]\()([^()\s]*)\s+(?=[^()]*\))
```

and `$1$2%20` replacement pattern. In Notepad++, press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` and after filling out the necessary fields, hit *`Replace in Files`*.

See the sample settings:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that VSCode doesn't match vertical whitespace characters by default. That makes this answer better than mine. Have my upvote :)

Comment: @41686d6564 More, `\[[^\]\[]*\]` does not match across lines either, so it also affects negated character classes. This is compliant with Vim, though here the similarity ends (as in Vim, one needs to use ``\_`` to enable linebreak matching while in VSCode, `\r` or `\n` must be added anywhere in the pattern (even `\n{0}` will do though it makes little sense in general).

Comment: Thanks for both your answers folks - annoyingly, this works for the find-replace in a file, but not in the find in files (ctrl/cmd-shift-f). Looks like they're working on slightly different versions of Regex - the find in files doesn't support variable lookbehinds.

Comment: @jt196 Right, it won't since the regex engine in the Find/Replace in Files uses Rust regex engine. not the ECMAScript 2018 compliant one in in-document search and replace. You will need to use your regex in Notepad++ Replace in Files feature.

Comment: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use/54227294#54227294) with some more info.

Comment: Also, and I guess this is my bad for having the idea, but this will match any whitespace until the end of the line after the `](` appearance. See [this example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5d%5c%28%5b%5e%5c%5d%5d*%29%5cs%2b&i=%23%23%23+Please+%5blogin%5d%28https%3a%2f%2fwww.accountingweb.co.uk%2fuser%2flogin%3fdestination%3dnode%2f81571%29+or+%5bregister%5d%28https%3a%2f%2fwww.accountingweb.co.uk%2fuser%2fregister%3fdestination%3dnode%2f81571%26referrer%3dcomment%29+to+join+the+discussion.&r=%2520).

Comment: @jt196 Added  a fix for the VSCode in-document S&R solution, and a NPP workaround for Replace in Files.

Comment: Weirdly, your fix works [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5d%5c%28%5b%5e%5c%5d%5d*%29%5cs%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=I+quoted+Michael+Porter+in+my+%5bALA+article%5d%28http%3a%2f%2fwww.alistapart.com%2farticles%2fredesignrealign%29+and+I%e2%80%99ll+do+so+again+here%3a+*%e2%80%9cThe+essence+of+strategy+is+choosing+what+not+to+do.%e2%80%9d&r=) but not in VSCode. Still getting the post link whitespace matches. Dude, don't pull your hair out over this you've already done enough!

Comment: @jt196 It works in VSCode, but only in the in-document S&R feature. As I said, it supports the ECMAScript 2018+ regex syntax, and the File search/replace is based on Rust regex, it won't allow any lookarounds. I really suggest switching to Notepad++ to replace in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as I'm on a Mac and didn't want to fire up a virtual PC to run Notepad++ (Sublime uses the same engine and Atom doesn't allow you exclude files), I used a combination of a Python script with @Wiktor Stribizew's answer for individual files that weren't picked up by the pattern for whatever reason.

```
md_url_pattern = r'(\[(.+)\])\(([^\)]+)\)'

def remove_spacing(match_obj):
    if match_obj.group(3) is not None:
        print("Match Object: " + match_obj.group(1) + "(" + re.sub(r"\s+", "%20", match_obj.group(3)) + ")")
        return match_obj.group(1) + "(" + re.sub(r"\s+", "%20", match_obj.group(3)) + ")"

# THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
this_folder = '<my_document_folder>' # fixed folder path
note_path = '<note_folder>' # change this 
full_path = os.path.join(this_folder, note_path)
directory = os.listdir(full_path)
os.chdir(full_path)

for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file, 'r')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    read_file = re.sub(md_url_pattern, remove_spacing, read_file)
    if not read_file:
        print("Empty file!")
    else:
        write_file = open(file,'w')
        write_file.write(read_file)
```

This script could do with a bit of tidying up and debugging (the odd weird empty file and no subfolder compatibility) but it was the best I could do.