# Regex removing bold markdown from inside codeblock only

Tags: regex

I'm editing in bulk some markdown files to be compliant with mkdocs syntax (material theme).

My previous documentation software accepted bold inside codeblock, but I discover now it's far from standard.

I've more than 10k codeblocks in this documentation, with more than 300 md files in nested directories, and most of them has `**` in order to bold some word.

To be precise I should make any CodeBlock from this:

````
this is a **code block** with some commands

```my_lexer
enable
configure **terminal**
interface **g0/0**
```
````

to this

````
this is a **code block** with some commands

```my_lexer
enable
configure terminal
interface g0/0
```
````

The fun parts:

- there are bold words in the rest of the document I would like to maintain (outside code block)
- not every row of the code block has bold in it
- not even every code block has necessarily bold in it

Now I'm using visual studio code with the substitute in files, and most of the easy regex I did for the porting is working. But it's not a perfect regex syntax (for examples, groups are denoted with $1 instead of \1 and maybe some other differences I don't know about).
But I accept other software (regex flavors) too if they are more regex compliant and accept 'replace in all files and subdirectories' (like notepad++, atom, etc..)

Sadly, I don't even know how to start something so complicated.
The most advanced I did is this: https://regex101.com/r/vRnkop/1 (there is also the text i'm using to test it)

````
(^```.*\n)(.*?\*\*(.*?)\*\*.*$\n)*
````

I hardly think this is a good start to do that!

Thanks

Comment: Can `**` appear in code-blocks when it is actually code (eg. C pointers) ? Can `**` span lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unix tools like `sed`. it is quite easy:

````
sed '/^```my_lexer/,/^```/ s/\*\*//g' orig.md >new.md
````

- `/regex1/,/regex2/ cmd` looks for a group of lines where the first line matches the first regex and the final line matches the second regex, and then runs `cmd` on each of them. This limits the replacements to the relevant sections of the file.
- `s/\*\*//g` does search and replace (I have assumed **any** instance of `**` should be deleted

---

Some versions of `sed` allow "in-place" editing with `-i`. For example, to edit `file.md` and keep original version as `file.md.orig`:

```
sed -i.orig '...' file.md
```

and you can edit multiple files with something like:

```
find -name '*.md' -exec sed -i.orig '...' \{} \+
```

Comment: I'm using this, but it just remove the first istance per row, just using it twice, perform as I need! This is awesome, MANY thanks! but I cannot understand how sed is working like this, normally I search globally, but here it seems you posed "limits" to it's research, am I wrong?

Comment: I should have had `g` flag to `s///` to delete all instances

Comment: yes, sed comands take either zero, one or two ["addresses"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_01). `s///` can take up to two - zero = every line, one = specific line, two = range of lines.

Comment: I've only one problem, I noticed that not ALL my code blocks have language, like in this pastebin https://pastebin.com/FajNQHmk and the double-stars in "normal text" get removed too (because I need to remove for the sed first address the "my_lexer" keyword). Now my chanche are either to put a language place-holder on the first triple-backtick (and I dunno how to distinguish between the first and the second!) or to parse everything wirth python and doing with it XD

Comment: `/^```/,/^```/ s/\*\*//g` should work, as long as they are always paired (It doesn't change the normal text in your pastebin example)

Comment: Hi, now I had to add the language to all the code blocks, hence, to the first occurrence of triple-backtick for each couple, I actually managed to do it with regex, python, and bash. But I'm sure there is a more clever way to do it, this is the answer to my own question, if you have time an opinion from you could help improve my regex skills, thanks a lot for everything: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73442927/adding-language-to-markdown-codeblock-in-bulk

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is not my forté but I did [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227294/9758194) you should be able to use PCRE2 regex syntax. Therefor try to substitute the following pattern with an empty string:

````
\*\*(?=(((?!^```).)*^```)(?:(?1){2})*(?2)$)
````

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ds9Wjq/1). The pattern seems a bit rocky and maybe someone else knows a much simpler pattern. However I did wanted to make sure this would both leave italic alone and would make bold+italic to italic. Note that `.` matches newline here.

Comment: This return an error: Invalid regula expression, invalid group.

Comment: If in the demo we put .NET (the vscode regex flavor) it returns the same error. This is a very nice regex indeed, thanks a lot for helping!