# Visual Studio Code - Ignore result if it contains certain string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I try to search for all occurences with `@author` in a project (I am using replace in various files) but I need to exclude a certain author.

My current search string is `@author`, this shows many results like:

```
@author John Doe
@author Frank Ermantraut
@author Amasty Team
```

How can I exclude results with "**Amasty Team**" in it?

Comment: Are you using the "magnifying glass" search and replace in various files, or just the in-document feature?

Comment: I am using the search for various files.

Comment: Then you can't, since Rust regex does not support lookarounds. Notepad++ has much better regex support for searching in different files.

Comment: Good to know, thank you :) I asked openAI btw and it gave me this regex which does not work `@author\s((?!Amasty Team).)*`

Comment: Do not ask AI questions like this, it can only provide very basic patterns. Or those that are already known. It cannot tell regex flavors either.

Comment: Yea, it failed on every regex question so far unfortunately.

Comment: openAI almost right: `@author\s(?!Amasty Team)`

Comment: I think `@author\s(?!Amasty Team)\S+` is correct

Comment: Why does your regex work in vscode despite lookarounds not being supported in the Rust regex engine?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74789031/836330 for an explanation.  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I tested it in an online regex tester. In vscode it does not work.

Comment: `@author\s(?!Amasty Team)\S+` works in vscode search across files.

Comment: It does not work if you search for various files.

Comment: Do you have the Regular Expression button enabled?

Comment: Not sure why it works now, probably human mistake by me. It works now with that regex I provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785291/visual-studio-code-ignore-result-if-it-contains-certain-string?noredirect=1#comment131987310_74785291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo with search across files working with a regex lookahead.

[image: search with regex lookahead]